# How to find/print index of max value in an array using pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need to find and print the index of the highest value in the array using pointers. My professor said it's possible to do with only the defined integers below (no counters or other valuables).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
int array[100], size, *MAX, *pi;
srand(time(NULL));
MAX = array;

printf("Insert array size:\n");
scanf("%d", &size);

for(pi=array; pi<array+size; pi++)
{
    *pi = ( rand()%100 ) + 1;
}

printf("\nArray elements:\n");
for(pi=array; pi<array+size; pi++)
    printf("%d\t", *pi);

for(pi=array+1; pi<array+size; pi++)
    if(*pi>*MAX)
{
    MAX = pi;
}

printf("\n\nMax is %d.", *MAX);
}
```

Comment: Record the *pointer* of the new max value, at the same time you record the new max value. Then its index will be the subtraction of pointers `pimax - niz`. But unfortunately what `niz` is, is unknown in your code.

Comment: MAX points to the max value in the array and you have a pointer to the start of the array and the memory is contiguous so you can subtract the MAX pointer from the array pointer to get the bytes and divide by the size of the stored datatype: (MAX-array) / sizeof(int)

Comment: @Iverelo don't divide by the size. Pointer arithmetic takes care of that for you. Oops in my first comment `MAX` is already the pointer to the max element, not its value. So its index is `MAX - array` but `niz` is undefined.

Comment: I do apologise, niz is array in this case, translated to english.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question if anyone stumbles on it. Thanks to Weather Vayne.

After determining the max value in the array, you find the index like this:

```
printf("%d", MAX - array);
```

The index shows places from 0 to n-1, so you can add +1 to make it show places from 1 to n (n is the number of elements in the array):

```
printf("%d", MAX - array + 1);
```